# Visual studio tries to run the program within the editor and crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a WPF projet that uses the WPFMediaKit and I have realised that it runs the camera and even the MessageBox.Show() code when in visual studio editing. That wouldn't be a problem if it was only the camera that it was trying to run its doing some other stuff that crash the instant i go into design view.

Why is this happening and where can it be turned off? Is there some sort of livepreview-off switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't stop it, it's made so user controls can draw themselves and react smartly to the user at design time.

You can however check for the `DesignMode` property inside your control and not do the camera operations (or anything at all if you wish).

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, however the usercontrol i am dealing with apparently doesn't have the IsDesignMode property or i couldn't find it. So i used if ( System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName != "devenv") and worked all the same. Thanks

Comment: @Sevki, oh apparently it's called just `DesignMode`, my bad.

Comment: I think the old WinForms one might have been called IsDesignTime, gets a bit confusing at times :)

Comment: @Matt, nah, it's the ASP.NET one that's `IsDesignMode`. I've been working on a large ASP.NET project recently and I've gotten used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with WPFMediaKit itself. It should have been written to take the IsDesignMode property into account as Blindy pointed out...